# iOS selector not called on background

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios7, nstimer

I used `NSTimer` to call a method every 24 hour, the timer is first initialised when app first launches and i set the interval to be `86400` as follows:

```
-(NSTimer*)todayTimesTimer{
   NSDate *now=[NSDate date];
   if (!_todayTimesTimer) {
    _todayTimesTimer=[[NSTimer alloc] initWithFireDate:now interval: 86400 target: self selector:@selector(businessMethod) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    }
   return _todayTimesTimer;
}
```

as i said the timer is first initialised when app is first launched as follows:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
  [self launchTodayTimesCalculationTimer];
}
```

and `launchTodayTimesCalculationTimer` is defined as follows:

```
-(void)launchTodayTimesCalculationTimer{
 NSRunLoop *runner = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
[runner addTimer:self.todayTimesTimer forMode: NSRunLoopCommonModes];
}
```

the problem is that the method `businessMethod` doesn't called when the app is in background, is there's a run mode for `NSTimer` that calls the selector in the background ? if not what are the possible ideas to run a selector when app is in background? thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to do when the timer fires?  There isn't a background mode that launches your app at a specific time.

Comment: Have u enabled  Project setting -> Target -> Capabilities -> Background modes -?

Comment: @Paulw11 i didn't want to launch the app at a specific time, i want to call a method while the app in the background

Comment: Sorry, I should clarify - I didn't mean launch into the foreground - even in the case of background execution your app is often relaunched by iOS - apps that are not in the foreground can be unloaded at any time and they are relaunched if required by the various background modes.  What are you wanting to do- there are specific background modes described in the iOS app programming guide.

Comment: simply, when the app launches an NSTimer is initialised and calls a method every 24 hour, i want that method to be called even if the user presses the home button and the app went to the background

Comment: You can't do that.  You can post a local notification, prompting the user to launch your app.  You can try background-refresh mode and check to see if it has been 24 hours, but there is no way that you can schedule your app to run at a specific time.

Comment: Apple is very strict about the background execution, unlike android apps iOS app are not allowed to run any code at any time while in background. There are specific cases you should learn it from [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/29948/backgrounding-for-ios). Also Local notification may help you

Comment: ok, how to use local notification to achieve that, could you please suggest me any link or tutorial that demonstrates that?